# Arduino MEGA 2650 R3 pin 13 LED is always on, unless I connect a multi-meter

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with the on-board LED staying lit up despite running a blink program.

I was running the blink program below, which writes HIGH/LOW to pin 13, but the light was solid. As soon as I connected the circuit between ground and pin 13 with the multi-meter, the LED started blinking.

[Here's a video showing my setup.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PYpEI92Qi-xkFwoBTkK9aaoFLRooXvc0) The video shows the "L" LED lit solid. The digital multi-meter (connected to pin 13 and GND) is switched from OFF to DCV, at which point the LED starts to blink. The wire connections are removed, and the LED is again lit up solid.

When the pin is set HIGH, the voltage reading is 5.07V. However, when the pin is set LOW, the voltage reads 0.61V whereas other pins read 100 times less, around 6mV.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(2000);
}
```

The question is why is this happening? Is my board bugged?

[Reference schematic linked here. "arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf)

Comment: You 'completed' (?) the circuit with a multimeter *in what setting*?

Comment: This is actually pretty odd. I’m looking forward to seeing some responses. You may want to edit the question to state which Arduino you’re using, and clarify the “completed the circuit” bit. Also, I believe the LED is yellow (amber) on the Mega board, not green.

Comment: Any chance of getting a schematic? Also, I would ask such questions at Arduino.SE rather than here.

Comment: Here’s the Mega schematic: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf ... otherwise, his schematic would just be a DVM across pin 13 (PB7) and ground.

Comment: The video seems to show the pin 13 LED stuck on until the digital multimeter (connected to 13 and GND) is switched from OFF to DCV at which stage it blinks. The meter seems a little slow to respond. This is weird.

Comment: @BlairFonville Could you please let the OP answer? AFAIK the blink program is supposed to work on any Arduino, provided no changes were done. With a reference Arduino schematic I'd be inclined to close this since the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: the multi-meter is a piece of garbage, and it's always slow to register voltage. @Transistor

Comment: @BlairFonville done ... i connected the circuit.

Comment: @BlairFonville one correction, it's an R3 2560 .. it's linked. thank you

Comment: Oh ok. Then I stand corrected. That’s actually a big difference since the pin now feeds a voltage follower.

Comment: Are you sure you have configured your IDE correctly for the board you have? If you've done everything right, I see no other explanation for this than a HW defect.

Comment: It's as if only the p-channel MOSFET is being driven, which I don't think can happen without a problem inside the MCU chip. The voltmeter (10M probably) is enough of a load to bring the 40nA bias current of the LM358 down to a low enough voltage to keep the LED off. Very strange.

Comment: I just added some more debugging info. If the voltage goes as low as 0.61V when the pin is set to LOW, would this be enough to light up the LED? I think it's weird how setting it to LOW would not make the voltage go to 0V. Other pins read 1.8mV when set to LOW.

Comment: in theory, the multi-meter is an infinite resistor. i don't have a 10K resistor handy, though.

Comment: I presume if you put a 10K resistor between 13 & GND it will appear to work properly? If not, it may be a bad solder joint to MCU pin 25 (or a cracked via on the PCB) and leakage due to residue. If so, it's probably a bad MCU chip.

Comment: The multimeter is not infinite, it's probably 10M or so. Do you have anything between 1K and 100K? If not, try bending the PCB and pressing on the MCU leads with something insulating like a chopstick.

Comment: i like your style... what's an MCU?

Comment: if i lick my finger and place it underneath the LED, making a wet finger contact the leads of the LED on the bottom of the board produces a flash whenever I touch it. It only flashes off when the pin is LOW. if the pin is HIGH, it's always on.

Comment: MCU = Microcontroller. I would suspect a bad PCB or solder joint to be much more likely than a bad MCU chip (which usually go short, not open). In any case, it appears to be a hardware problem so you may wish to return it if it is under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Connect 10k PUl-up resistor(Similair like on imput) to the Pin 13 in some cases internal induction on some supplies may generate enough background voltage to keep LED on
although internal capacitance may slow down blinking (dimming).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjiVNO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Tomas, but you seem to be guessing. If you look at the schematic for this Arduino you will see that the LED is not driven directly from the GPIO. There is a buffer. There is no "background voltage" - the Arduino has an on-board regulator. Internal capacitance does not slow down blinking. Blinking is controlled by the program. Keep studying.